# Getting data correctly from <span> tag with beautifulsoup, python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I am crawling a sightseeing and activity page in order to get the price mentioned in that page. In the following block the price is mentioned:

```
<div class="price-info" data-origin-price="1200" data-lowest-price="1200.0"  data-origin-ccy="JPY" data-discount-percentage="60">
      <span class="before-discount-row">
        <span class="before-discount">25.12</span>
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
      </span>
    <span class="price-row">
      <span class="price-prefix">From</span>
      <span class="price">10.05</span>
      <span class="currency">EUR</span>
    </span>
```

I´am able to get the price in Yen (1200). In the next step, I would also like to get the price back in EUR. In particular the price in the following sub block:

```
<span class="price-row">
  <span class="price-prefix">From</span>
  <span class="price">10.05</span>
  <span class="currency">EUR</span>
</span>
```

But somehow, I´m running into walls. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import urllib

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}

RegionID = "tokyo"

r = requests.get("https://www.govoyagin.com/things_to_do/japan/" +  str(RegionID) + "?page=0" + str(page))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "activity-list"})
for item in g_data:
      prices = item.find_all("div", {"class": "price-info"})
      for t in price:
          Price_final = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
          print(Price_final)
```

That is the output that I get instead of 10.05 EUR

```
[<span class="price"></span>]
```

Can someone help me out? Is there any way to just get the number out of the span?

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: The content is dynamic that's the issue.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic is there any way to solve that problem?

Comment: Yes, using a "fake/automated/emulated browser" Selenium, look it up on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget a last for loop:

```
g_data = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "activity-list"})
for item in g_data:
      prices = item.find_all("div", {"class": "price-info"})
      for t in prices:
          final_prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
          for p in final_prices:
              print(p)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work, still getting the same output.